# Fullcalendar popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I wanna make popover for add new event when user will click to day ("select" callback in jsEvent.pageX and jsEvent.pageY parameter but Idea where is this popup still sticked on clicked element looks better.

So my working code for stick popup to some element :

```
$('#my-button').popover({header: '#my-popover > .headerrr', content: '#my-popover > .contenttt'});
```

html

```
<a id="my-button">Popover</a>
```

I already tried something like this:

```
select: function(start, end, allDay, jsEvent) {

  element.popover({header: '#my-popover > .headerrr', content: '#my-popover > .contenttt'});

// ........

},
```

But isn't working.

Any help will very greatful!

Comment: From my experince i have tried pop-overs and it was a pain in A...My advice is to have a outside( ouside calendar div) dialog and call it when you need. If you need examples let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add,

```
var element = $(jsEvent.srcElement);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have similar issue with a modal. 
I bind the event over the eventRender of the calendar. And fill over the eventClick.

```
var calendarOptions = {
      eventRender: function (event, element) {
            if (event.className[0] === "someClassName") {
             //here i bind, the link of the event        
            };
          },
      eventClick: function (event, jsEvent) {
        if (event.className[0] === "someClassEvent") {
          //or here
        }
};
```

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/mouse/eventClick/
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/